# Compatability of cross-built COFF files and MSVS

Tags: c, linker, static-libraries, linker-errors, cross-build

I have cross-built a win32 static library using `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`on a linux box.

I have inspected the resulting .lib file with `nm` on the linux side and see:

```
bsd_offset.o:
         U __assert
00000000 T _bsd_offset
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 i .drectve
         U _flp3
00000004 C _randNo
00000000 r .rdata
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text

bsdi.o:
00000000 T _bsdi
00000000 b .bss
         U _clp3
00000000 d .data
00000000 i .drectve
00000004 C _randNo
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text

...
```

I have also inspected the .lib file with `dumpbin /symbols` on the windows side and see:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file libLib_rel.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00000000 DEBUG  notype       Filename     | .file
    bsd_offset.c
002 00000000 SECT1  notype ()    External     | _bsd_offset
    tag index 00000000 size 00000000 lines 00000000 next function 00000000
004 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .text
    Section length   BF, #relocs    4, #linenums    0, checksum        0
006 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .data
    Section length    0, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
008 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .bss
    Section length    0, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00A 00000000 SECT4  notype       Static       | .rdata
    Section length   1A, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00C 00000000 SECT6  notype       Static       | .drectve
    Section length   2C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00E 00000000 SECT7  notype       Static       | .rdata$zzz
    Section length   1A, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
010 00000004 UNDEF  notype       External     | _randNo
011 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _flp3
012 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | __assert

String Table Size = 0x35 bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00000000 DEBUG  notype       Filename     | .file
    bsdi.c
002 00000000 SECT1  notype ()    External     | _bsdi
    tag index 00000000 size 00000000 lines 00000000 next function 00000000
004 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .text
    Section length   70, #relocs    1, #linenums    0, checksum        0
006 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .data
    Section length    0, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
008 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .bss
    Section length    0, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00A 00000000 SECT5  notype       Static       | .drectve
    Section length   26, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00C 00000000 SECT6  notype       Static       | .rdata$zzz
    Section length   1A, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
00E 00000004 UNDEF  notype       External     | _randNo
00F 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | _clp3

String Table Size = 0x29 bytes

...
```

A colleague is attempting to build an exe using the lib using MSVS2008 and is seeing errors like:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: StaticLinkExample, Configuration: Release Win32 ------

1>Linking...

1>testLib_rel.lib(initialise.o) : warning LNK4229: invalid directive '/aligncomm:_randNo,2' encountered; ignored

1>testLib_rel.lib(lib.o) : warning LNK4229: invalid directive '/aligncomm:_randNo,2' encountered; ignored

...

1>   Creating library D:\Software\ThirdParty\Lib_v230\Trial\StaticLinkExample\Release\StaticLinkExample.lib and object D:\Software\ThirdPart\Lib_v230\Trial\StaticLinkExample\Release\StaticLinkExample.exp

1>testLib_rel.lib(shared.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___ms_vsnprintf

1>testLib_rel.lib(iniparser.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___ms_vsnprintf

1>testLib_rel.lib(utility.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___ms_vsnprintf

1>testLib_rel.lib(load_glf.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms

1>testLib_rel.lib(utility.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___chkstk_ms

1>testLib_rel.lib(lib.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fmax

1>testLib_rel.lib(lib.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fmin

1>StaticLinkExample.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol bsd_offset

1>StaticLinkExample.exp : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol bsdi
```

Do the `nm` and `dumpbin` outputs look sensible. If the symbols are there in the static library why would the link errors be occuring. Could it be that somehow the cross-built lib is not binary compatible with MSVS 2008?